Using Shared channels to push a channel to multiple teams? Questions about permissions
We're trying again to setup a Teams environment for our company.
Our corporate structure is rather messy due to a couple of acquisitions and spin-off companies.
There are 5 companies altogether, each with several locations.
The director pushing hardest for Teams really wants a simple layout, with one team for each company. The owner wants teams for each department so that we can better tailor channels.
I happen to lean towards department-specific teams, though I see the value of a dead-simple format for initial rollout. Users bouncing off entirely is a real risk with these guys. It's probably my fault for voicing the downsides of a simple company-specific approach lol.

I see we can now create "shared channels" that can be pushed to multiple Teams. This could help reconcile these two builds a bit.
My question: At first glance, it looks the permissions management is a bit lackluster for shared channels. How can I limit the access to the channel while still having it appear in multiple locations?
Example: Say I have "Company A Leadership" that lives on the Leadership team. I can share it to the Company A team, but it looks as if that channel will then be visible to everyone in that team. I'm not sure how to limit the access to the channel while still having it appear in multiple locations.
I don't want any situations where people speak a little too freely, not realizing it's visible to everyone. But I don't want channels where people won't immediately know where to post, or not think to look at.

I think I discovered a solution. I should create the shared channel in the more-general team, and then share it to the Leadership team. When done that way, only those manually added to the channel in its hometeam have access to it.
